# Variable is not of the type class

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a custom class for holding a collection of data.

I use this class throughout my code, and it works without a hitch, except for in one place, when I need to pass the class object to a method.  Here is some very basic code to demonstrate what I am seeing.

```
public class doSomething
    static void myMethod(customClass_myItem) {}

public class customClass
    public str classMethod() {}

form method
    customClass myItem = new customClass();
    myItem.classMethod(); //this works, so I know the class is good
    doSomething::myMethod(myItem); //Gives error: variable is not of the type CLASS.
```

I am completely lost here.  If I couldn't use the class at all, I would understand, but with it not working when passed to another method..  doesn't make any sense.  If I put in a breakpoint, the debugger indicates myItem is a class of the correct type.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `myMethod` expects an object of class `customClass_myItem` (or a descendant) not `customClass`.

If you change your parameter type to `object` it should work.

```
static void myMethod(Object o) {}
```